# How to know app resubmission is successfull on google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I submitted an app on the Google Play store.
But my app was rejected by the Google Play store.
Now I resubmitted my app.
But I did not get any message that my resubmission is being successful.
Still it is showing rejected like as previous.
is it submitted successfully??
Any information would be appreciable.

Comment: How much time has passed since then? This may take several hours.

Comment: Are you sure that you fixed the reason of reject?

Comment: @ Dmitriy Kholin - It has passed about half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a notification that informs you that the app is live